# How to read the content in the .cfg file and parse them into a dictionary?

Tags: dolphindb

How to read the content in the .cfg file and parse them into a dictionary?

The configurations are as below:

```py
uid = reader
pwd = xxxxxx
driver =MySQL
port = 43306
db = xxxxxx
ip = 192.168.xxx.xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done using configparser in Python. see documentation - https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 0):

Custom functions, read CFG files and convert them into dictionaries.

```py
def getMysqlConnDict() {
    f = file("/data/software/dolphin/server/mysqlconn.cfg")
    arr = f.readLines()
    
    connDict = dict(STRING, ANY)
    for(i in 0:arr.size()) {
        connDict[trim(split(arr[i], "=")[0])] = trim(split(arr[i], "=")[1])
    }
    return connDict
}

connDict = getMysqlConnDict()
```